# Por que esta pergunta merece ser excluída?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Ao ver essa pergunta...

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5291/sucess-ajax-retorna-200-ok-mas-retorno-json-nao-e-exibido

...eu instantaneamente e intuitivamente pensei: "o *site* ficaria muito melhor sem esta pergunta - ela é pura perda de tempo para qualquer um que passe por ela".

Porém, eu não tomei nenhuma atitude. Não cliquei em "sinalizar" por exemplo. Pela simples razão de que eu não saberia **dizer o motivo**. Apesar de ser óbvio que ela tem motivos para ser excluída... que o *site* fica melhor sem ela... eu não sei **argumentar** oferecendo objetivamente a razão.

Apenas "**perda de tempo**" vem na minha cabeça. Mas isso responde "Porque esta pergunta merece ser excluída?" - deve haver uma resposta mais eloquente ou melhor elaborada.

Comment: Não sei se deveria ser excluída, mas certamente fechada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-apenas-procuram-code-review-for-typos

Comment: Não tem equivalente ao "too localized" no SO em português?

Comment: Nem em inglês tem. É off-topic.

Comment: Votei para fechar com a razão "other" e colocando uma tradução do exposto no link acima (i.e. a resposta do @bigown). Se não for a melhor saída, me fale e eu retiro o comentário e/ou o voto para fechar.

Comment: IDEM: usei a razão "other" também, e deixei explicado no comentário; IBIDEM: se outro curso de ação é melhor, favor avisar.

Comment: Re: "too localized" - se não tem mais, pelo menos tinha... eu  me lembro! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized

Comment: Ah! Aqui está anunciado o fim do "Too localized" em prol do "Off-topic": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons

Comment: Ironia: me passou pela cabeça - "será que esta questão que fiz aqui no Meta é 'too localized'!?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sou a favor de oficializarmos esse motivo de fechamento no diálogo de off-topic.

Comment: Inspirado no comentário do @mgibsonbr, abri uma nova discussão: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/835/quais-motivos-de-fechamento-devemos-ter-em-descontextualizada-outros

Answer (score 3):

## Eu já votei para excluir.

O meu voto foi baseado em quatro motivos:

1. Votei para excluir pelo simples motivo de que a pergunta trata um problema que se resume a falta de atenção do utilizador. Não vejo como esta pergunta aberta ou fechada possa vir a beneficiar alguém no futuro, pelo que a presença da mesma só servirá para "ocupar espaço".
2. A pergunta uma vez fechada, sem respostas e sem votações vai ser automaticamente excluída pelo sistema implementado para "limpar os sites". Se assim é, não vejo porque manter a mesma no resultados de pesquisa por dois, três ou seis meses que sejam.
3. O autor da pergunta deu conta do seu *typo* **seis minutos** após colocar a mesma aqui no site:

   - Respondeu à pergunta com a solução? **Não**
   - Eliminou a pergunta? **Não**

   Ao invés de agir de forma "normal" dentro do expectável no site, o autor deixou um comentário a dar conta que a pergunta estava resolvida.
4. Dá para ver pelos restantes comentários na pergunta que não sou o único a achar que a mesma não tem grande utilidade nem agora nem no futuro, o que ajudou a decidir que mais vale excluir a mesma:

   > Essa pergunta foi causada por um problema que não pode ser reproduzido ou um simples erro tipográfico. Embora perguntas similares podem ser on-topic aqui, esta foi resolvida de uma maneira que não deve ser útil a leitores futuros. Isso pode ser evitado com frequência identificando e inspecionando de perto o menor programa necessário para reproduzir o problema antes de postar. –  mgibsonbr 12/02 às 1:37
   >
   > Questão muito restrita: é apenas um erro de digitação; não vai ajudar a mais ninguém. Apesar de ter sido bem feita e não ter nada de errado em si, agora que está resolvida tornou-se perda de tempo para os demais. –  J. Bruni 12/02 às 1:37